# Maven dependency for pd4ml

Tags: java, web-services, rest, html-to-pdf, pd4ml

HI I searched on google and did not find the dependency for PD4ML.I have added the jar manually but everytime i do ***mvn clean install*** it is giving me compile time error

> error: package org.zefer.pd4ml does not exist
>
> org.zefer.pd4ml does not exist

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer after hours spending on it

step one :download the pd4ml.jar

step two :Run the below command on command prompt

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=D:\<path to your downloaded jar>\pd4ml.jar -DgroupId=com.pd4ml.utilities -DartifactId=pd4ml -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

step 3 : add the dependency on pom.xml based on the groupId and artifactsId you have provided

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pd4ml.utilities</groupId>
        <artifactId>pd4ml</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Remember `ss_css2 jar` is also require to run the pd4ml follow the above steps to create a mvn depedency for this jar

Comment: Really helpful. I can solve the same issue with your answer. I kept ss_css2 jar inside the folder where I  kept the pd4ml.jar. Thanks a lot

Comment: BTW: open source ss_css2 jar CSS parser library is not needed since PD4ML v3.9.8.

The actual PD4ML v4 Maven instructions can be found there: https://pd4ml.tech/support-topics/maven/

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a dependency to the pom.xml file?
Something like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.zefer.pd4ml</groupId>
    <artifactId>pd4ml</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3fx5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your pom.xml add the repository first to resolve the pd4ml as below:

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
     <id>my-repo2</id>
     <name>your custom repo</name>
     <url>http://maven.scandilabs.com/repository</url>
   </repository>
 </repositories>
```

and then in the dependencies add dependency as below:

```
<dependency>
    groupId>org.zefer.pd4ml</groupId>
    <artifactId>pd4ml</artifactId>
    <version>370fx2</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: what is the taglib uri for this to include it in jsp page

Answer (score 0):

Add the repository `https://pd4ml.tech/maven2/` and the dependency `com.pd4ml` to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project ...>
  <groupId>de.luckydonald.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>42805145</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>pd4ml</id>
      <url>https://pd4ml.tech/maven2/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- html to rtf -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.pd4ml</groupId>
      <artifactId>pd4ml</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```